# Calling a Derived Class method from a Void Pointer cast to a Base Object

Tags: c++, inheritance, void-pointers

I want to call an overridden method in a derived class from a void pointer. This fails at runtime because the virtual Base::foo() method is invoked, rather than Derived::foo(). This is how the relevant code works:

```
Class Base  
{  
public:  
    Base();  
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

Class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived();
    void foo();
}

int main()
{
    Derived* dv = new Derived();
    void* ptr = dv;

    static_cast<Base*>(ptr)->foo();
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me (derived method is called). However I believe what you are trying to do is actually undefined behaviour, because the standard does not appear to guarantee that if you convert `Derived*` to `void*` and then to `Base*` that it'll actually point to the right object.

Comment: For example, the compiler is allowed to put the `Base` subobject at the end of the `Derived` object instead of at the beginning, in which case `static_cast<Base*>(ptr)` likely won't point to the `Base` subobject, since it'll point to the *beginning* of the `Derived` object.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way this can work other than by luck. Since this is a `static_cast`, the conversion must be known at compile time. But because the pointer is a `void *`, there's no way the compiler can know how the pointer needs to converted to point to the instance of the base inside the derived.